# RaphaelJS subpath on transformed path

Tags: raphael

I'm having issues with creating a subpath on a path that has been transformed. It seems that the subpath is generated with the original position of the path in reference rather than the post transform location of the path. How do I get around this?

```
var paper = new Raphael("canvas");
var lineParams = {
    fill: "#ff0",
    gradient: "90-#526c7a-#64a0c1",
    stroke: "#3b4449",
        "stroke-width": 2
};

var line1 = paper.path("M 0 50 h 200").attr(lineParams);
line1.transform("T100,100");
if (line1 != null) {
    var lineBBox = line1.getBBox()
    var lineEnd = lineBBox.x2 - lineBBox.x;
    var lineTipStart = lineEnd - 10;
    var lineTipString = line1.getSubpath(lineTipStart, lineEnd);
    var lineTip = paper.path(lineTipString);
    lineTip.attr({
        "stroke-width": 2,
        stroke: '#FF0000'
    });
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/nzwthkmo/1/

Answer (score 1):

Its not so much a case of getting around it, as realising what its doing, and deciding how you want to approach it.

The original path has a transform applied to it, the path is still exactly the same. So do you want the same thing (maybe your code will be expecting that), or do you want a new modified path with new baked coordinates with the transform in place.

So depending on what you will do in the future with it, you could either

a) Simply apply the same transform to the subpath...

```
var lineTip = paper.path(lineTipString).transform("T100,100");
```

or

b) create a new path where the coordinates are all permanently transformed...

```
var lineTip = paper.path( Raphael.transformPath(lineTipString, "T100,100") )
```

[fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/nzwthkmo/3/) with both examples (one commented out).

Comment: Well, the problem is that at the time I'm generating the line tip I do not necessarily know how many transforms the path has undergone. The path is draggable, so the user may have moved it around freely for a while. Basically, I want to create the line tip at any given time and have it take into account the current location of the path. I guess maybe there's no good way to do that other than if I get the transform matrix of the path and use that?

Comment: Yes, sounds reasonable, just get whatever the existing transform is. Another idea is you could clone the original path (so any transforms copy with it), and just change the 'd' attribute to the subPath maybe ? (not tried this)